# How to call a WebApi controller method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I've just created asp.net mvc 4 app and added default webapi controller

```
public class UserApiController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/default1
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/default1/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/default1
    public void Post(string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/default1/5
    public void Put(int id, string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/default1/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

Then i was trying to call method get() by typing `http://localhost:51416/api/get` in the browser but getting error:

```
<Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:51416/api/get'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No type was found that matches the controller named 'get'.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

my route config:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                //defaults: new { controller = "UserApiController", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Why it is not working by default?
What can i do in order to fix that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to put `get` in the URL because GET is type of the HTTP verb.

And by default the browsers sends GET request if you type in an URL.

So try it with `http://localhost:51416/api/`

Because `UserApiController` is the default api controller if you uncomment the line `defaults: new { controller = "UserApiController"...` in your routing config

Note that you don't need the "controller" suffix when specifying your routes so the correct `dafaults` settings is :`defaults: new { controller = "UserApi", id = RouteParameter.Optional }`
)

or you need to explicitly specifying the controller `http://localhost:51416/api/userapi`

You can start learning about Wep.API and a HTTP verb based routing conventions on the [ASP.NET Web API site](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

Comment: was trying `http://localhost:51416/api` getting The resource cannot be found. but `http://localhost:51416/api/userapi` working :). How to fix `http://localhost:51416/api` route?

Comment: To make `http://localhost:51416/api` work **uncomment** this line from the routing: `defaults: new { controller = "UserApiController", id = RouteParameter.Optional }` because there you specify the default controller for the route

Comment: was tying with `defaults: new { controller = "UserApiController", id = RouteParameter.Optional }` but still getting The resource cannot be found. when calling `localhost:51416/api/`

Comment: Sorry, you don't need the controller suffix try it with  `new { controller = "UserApi", id = RouteParameter.Optional }`